# Model Testing Accuracy Stuck - Keras Transfer Learning

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to create an ML model that would classify satellite images of roads according to their quality. This is a four-classification problem (roads are classified as "Good", "Fair", "Poor", and "Bad").

I am trying to create model by using transfer learning. I have followed the steps in Keras documentation that can be found here: https://keras.io/guides/transfer_learning/ . **Currently, I am stuck with my model having around ~40% testing accuracy** (result of ``` model.evaluate(``) ```)despite all the changes I've tried to do.

Some tuning that I have tried include:

- Increasing the epochs (at some point, the model just reaches 99% training accuracy which I think is just overfitted at this point)
- Using different architectures (Xception, ResNet, DenseNet, AlexNet, etc.)
- Using different learning rates (0.1 - 0.000001)
- Using different optimizers (SGD, Adam, RMSProp)
- Resizing my dataset of images (150x150, 200x200, 224x224, etc.)

Down below are some snippets of my code.

**Model Definition**

```
model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(keras.applications.Xception(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_shape=(150, 150, 3)))
model.add(keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(100))
model.add(keras.layers.Activation(keras.activations.relu))
model.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(4))
model.add(keras.layers.Activation(keras.activations.softmax))

model.layers[0].trainable=False
```

**Model Compilation**

For this one, I use categorical crossentropy because I have one hot encoded the labels of my dataset using `tf.onehot`.

```
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001), metrics=['accuracy'])
```

After training for a few epochs, I then unfreeze the pre-built architecture and continue training for more epochs. I do that using the code snippet below.

```
model.layers[0].trainable=True
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-5), metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

**Model Summary**

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 xception (Functional)       (None, 5, 5, 2048)        20861480  
                                                                 
 flatten (Flatten)           (None, 51200)             0         
                                                                 
 dense (Dense)               (None, 100)               5120100   
                                                                 
 activation (Activation)     (None, 100)               0         
                                                                 
 batch_normalization_4 (Batc  (None, 100)              400       
 hNormalization)                                                 
                                                                 
 dropout (Dropout)           (None, 100)               0         
                                                                 
 dense_1 (Dense)             (None, 4)                 404       
                                                                 
 activation_1 (Activation)   (None, 4)                 0         
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 25,982,384
Trainable params: 5,120,704
Non-trainable params: 20,861,680
_________________________________________________________________
```

As for my dataset, I have around 40,000 satellite images of roads classified into four. I re-labeled them with integers so I could use one-hot encoding. They look like this in my system directory and I load them using `keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory()`.

```
Directory
├───training
│   ├───0
│   ├───1
│   └───2
|   └───3
└───testing
│   ├───0
│   ├───1
│   └───2
|   └───3
└───validation
    ├───0
    ├───1
    └───2
    └───3
```

I have checked through and through and I can't seem to find anything to change anymore.

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO! Just as a heads up, given the way the SO community works, where questions are intended to have direct, justifiably correct answers, an open-ended question like yours might have some trouble. That being said, I'll try to give some feedback where I can in the comment thread

Comment: 1) Possibly not enough learning allowed in the right places. When you do transfer learning the way you're doing, you're basically hoping to take the backbone of the model, which has learned how to nicely extract features from (some kind) of image. However, what you've done here is kind of force yourself into a hole. You're using imagenet weights, but imagenet images are nothing like the images you're training off of. Maybe basic features, but the important overarching attention the model should be paying will not be nicely tuned.

Comment: To make things worse, you're only allowing 2 layers to train. Think about it like this: your model, which was trained on imagenet, preprocessing data assuming a data distribution similar to imagenet, yet suddenly it has 2 computational steps to shift to satellite imagery. That's not a lot of space to learn everything about satellites. And having basically only a single dense layer that is 5 million trainable parameters is tough, and bound to overfit in practice.

Comment: So what I'm getting to is: leave more space for learning. How? Either you can add some more convolutional layers before flattening, *or*, what I usually do is unfreeze the top `k` layers of the backbone. So lower-level features are still frozen (those usually transfer well), but it allows the backbone to be more flexible and fit better to your domain. And make sure by the time you're flattening your representation, you shouldn't be more than several thousand dimensions.

Comment: 2) You're overfitting. What does this mean? The model/architecture you're using is complex enough to capture the data, but it's focusing on the wrong kind of info. A lot of that could be due to what I wrote above. But it might also mean your problem doesn't *need* transfer learning. Again, the model you're using was trained on imagenet, which is a HUGE dataset. It could just mean your problem is better solved using a less complex model, which would make it harder for the model to memorize the training set (in a way what overfitting is) and can actually learn the desired features.

Comment: @MZ Yeah, it's an open ended question and it's difficult to answer but thank you for the comments. I am new to machine learning so the stuff you said about model complexity gives me something new to try. I will look into those stuff more and maybe there's something I could tune there that would solve my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather hard thing to answer without additional context. As you've already mentioned having a 99% test accuracy is likely to be an overfitting of your classifier. Nevertheless this doesn't necessarily mean that it's the main issue here.

There could be multiple reasons for this some of them might be:

1. Your data is imbalanced in terms of class distribution
2. Your data is unevenly distributed within each dataset (train, val, test)
3. There is some error within the preprocessing (e.g. pictures are labeled falsely.)

After validating the above, maybe try some of the following:

1. Experiment with different regularization techniques (e. g. use early stopping)
2. Try augmenting your data (e. g. flip your images)